# Как сделать, чтоб программа завершалась только при вводе в консоль команды выхода/закрытии окна консоли?

Tags: java, c#, c++

Есть код:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
  Info();
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа постоянно считывала ввод с консоли и закрывалась только при команде пользователя(например, "`exit`").

Comment: Нашел вариант - используя while(true), возможно есть более лаконичные варианты?

Comment: Лаконичней - goto.

Comment: Используйте ```while(true)``` и все будет хорошо (куда уж лаконичней то?). Не надо выдумывать другие велосипеды.

Comment: можно использовать `do { ... } while(command.ToLower() != "exit")` - цикл с постусловием

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К примеру так (код C#):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Info();

    string command;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter command: ");
        command = Console.ReadLine();              
    } while (command != null && !command.Equals("exit"));
}

private static void Info()
{            
    Console.WriteLine("Info");
}
```

как только будет введено слово `exit`, программа завершит выполнение. Единственное, советую использовать [Console.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо `Console.ReadKey()`. Считываем не символ, а строку символов.

Касаемо комментария к вопросу. На мой взгляд, использование кода `while(true)` - является признаком плохого тона в программировании. Старайтесь избегать написания подобного кода.